# Player is instantly teleported back

Tags: unity

I built a teleporter that changes a players position and rotation.
He is instantly teleported back. Why?

I'm using the standard FPS Controller.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of descending into madness, i found a comment on a youtube video that mentioned, that **CharacterController** has a bug that causes this problem when using **Move()** and similar methods.

**Fix:** 
use **Physics.SyncTransforms()** before doing that or set the **Auto Sync Transforms** option in the settings.

Credits to the youtube-comment i could not find anymore.